# PHP Contact Form - Reply-To

Tags: php, forms

I've looked at the other questions about PHP Contact Form and tried different options but nothing seems to work, so here is my code. I can't make the Reply-To to have the sumbitter email. In reply-to I get: $email@hn02.wiroos.com  (wiroos is the hosting company name), everything else is working fine.

The form:

```
<form action="procesar_form.php" method="post" name="formulario" id="formulario" onsubmit='return validarFormulario()'>
        <label for="nombre">Nombre </label>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" size="60"/>

        <label for="apellido">Apellido </label>
        <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido" size="60"/>

        <label for="email">Email </label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="60"/>

        <label for="comentarios">Comentarios</label>
        <textarea name="comentarios" id="comentarios" cols="44" rows="10"></textarea>

        <input type="button" name="enviar" id="enviar" value="Enviar" onclick="validarFormulario()" /></textarea>

</form>
```

PHP code:

```
$to      = 'elunicotomas@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Contacto PowerFitness';
$message = 'Nombre: ' . $_REQUEST['nombre'] . "\r\n" .
            'Apellido: ' . $_REQUEST['apellido'] . "\r\n" .
            'Email: ' . $_REQUEST['email'] . "\r\n" .
            'Comentarios: ' . $_REQUEST['comentarios'];
$headers = 'From: Contacto PowerFitness pedidos@powerfitness.com.ar' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: pedidos@powerfitness.com.ar' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

header("Location: ../../index.html");
```

I sent an email to my address (from the form) so I can see the email source and here it is:

```
> Delivered-To: elunicotomas@gmail.com Received: by 10.60.132.7 with
> SMTP id oq7csp23527oeb;
>         Sun, 24 Mar 2013 17:57:27 -0700 (PDT) X-Received: by 10.236.160.195 with SMTP id u43mr5762986yhk.104.1364173047442;
>         Sun, 24 Mar 2013 17:57:27 -0700 (PDT) Return-Path: <nobody@hn02.wiroos.com> Received: from hn02.wiroos.com
> (hn02.wiroos.com. [199.115.114.195])
>         by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id h65si7425664yhk.272.2013.03.24.17.57.27
>         (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
>         Sun, 24 Mar 2013 17:57:27 -0700 (PDT) Received-SPF: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of nobody@hn02.wiroos.com
> designates 199.115.114.195 as permitted sender)
> client-ip=199.115.114.195; Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
>        spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of nobody@hn02.wiroos.com designates 199.115.114.195 as permitted sender)
> smtp.mail=nobody@hn02.wiroos.com Received: from nobody by
> hn02.wiroos.com with local (Exim 4.80)    (envelope-from
> <nobody@hn02.wiroos.com>)     id 1UJvj2-0002cx-SK     for
> elunicotomas@gmail.com; Sun, 24 Mar 2013 21:57:25 -0300 To:
> elunicotomas@gmail.com Subject: Contacto PowerFitness X-PHP-Script:
> powerfitness.com.ar/contacto/procesar_form.php for 200.70.31.20 From:
> Contacto PowerFitness pedidos@powerfitness.com.ar Reply-To:
> $email@hn02.wiroos.com X-Mailer: PHP/5.3.21 Message-Id:
> <E1UJvj2-0002cx-SK@hn02.wiroos.com> Date: Sun, 24 Mar 2013 21:57:24
> -0300 X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname -
> hn02.wiroos.com X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com X-AntiAbuse:
> Originator/Caller UID/GID - [99 32007] / [47 12] X-AntiAbuse: Sender
> Address Domain - hn02.wiroos.com X-Get-Message-Sender-Via:
> hn02.wiroos.com: uid via acl_c_vhost_owner from authenticated_id:
> nobody from /only user confirmed/virtual account not confirmed
> X-Source:  X-Source-Args: /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -k start -DSSL 
> X-Source-Dir: powerfitness.com.ar:/public_html/contacto
> 
> Nombre: Tomas Apellido: Perez Ponisio Email: elunicotomas@gmail.com
> Comentarios: 132465
```

Comment: what problem exactly, are you having?  is it not sending?  not sending the right data?  are you getting errors?  are you stuck on a part?

Comment: quoting from your code: 'Reply-To: pedidos@powerfitness.com.ar'

Comment: the problem is that in that I have in Reply-To: $email@hn02.wiroos.com

Comment: @elunicotomas What? si es mas facil para ti ... hable en espanol

Comment: Try using `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: I've just tried $_POST instead of $_REQUEST and is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following things:

1) Use \n instead of \r\n. Maybe your host is using linux delimiters and is just not recognizing the windows return carriage.

2) If that didn't work, try changing the case of Reply-To to Reply-to. Some mail servers are case sensitive

3) If that didn't work either, send an email using your form, and when you receive it, open the source of the email, and check the headers that are included, and post them here to see how your mail server is actually recognizing the headers you are trying to use.

Comment: I tried:
1) Didn't work
2) Didn't work either
3) I am editing my anwser and postin the source of an email sonet to my actual email adress

Comment: Hmm.... please try one more thing: Change  From: Contacto PowerFitness pedidos@powerfitness.com.ar  to From: Contacto PowerFitness <pedidos@powerfitness.com.ar> and Reply-To: pedidos@powerfitness.com.ar to Reply-To: <pedidos@powerfitness.com.ar>

Comment: Mickle, I got it to work by using " instead of ', the final piece of code is:  $headers = "From: Contacto PowerFitness pedidos@powerfitness.com.ar" . "\n" . Thanks!

Comment: elunicotomas lol, I see, that was a quite strange problem. Glad to know that you solved it.